# Origins of the Equals Signs

Tags: notation, math-history

Some authors use different equals signs for different purposes. For the most part, they are "$=$", "$\equiv$", "$:=$", and "$:\equiv$'.  I read that "$=$" dates back to 1557, and is of mathematical origin.

What about the others?  I have read that "$:=$" appears in some programming languages from the $70$'s.  But, does it occur earlier? What about $\equiv$ and $:\equiv$, what are their origins?

Comment: I use $\equiv$ to mean "equivalent" which is not exactly the same thing as equal.  It has been a long time since I have done any programming but as I remember $a:=b$ defines $a$ as equal to $b$ where "$a=b$" is a logical proposition, returning a true or false result.

Comment: the sign $\equiv$ is a logical symbol, sometimes used in mathematics to denote congruence. It means that the chain of symbols to both sides represent the same thing. The double point $:$ in both notations means "definition". This is to differentiate from an equation or a consequential identity.

Comment: The use of $\equiv$ for congruence is introduced by Gauss in 1801 ([an online reference](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/history/nth.html), another reference is paragraph 408 of Florian Cajor's book [A history of mathematical notations](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486677664/)).

Comment: This question may be worth moving to or asking instead on [history of science and mathematics stackexchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).  In any case, another possibly useful reference would be [Gentzen's paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002375508&physid=PHYS_0182) where he tried to standardize various logical symbols.  He mentions that he opted not to use $\equiv$ in the same way as Russel since it has other uses elsewhere in mathematical literature.

Comment: @DougM my memory is that $a = b$ defines $a$ but $a==b$ is the logical proposition.

Comment: @DougM In my experience in more modern languages `a=b` sets a equal to b, whereas `a := b` throws an error. The logical statement is `a==b` as @fleablood said.

Comment: The use of $\equiv$ for geometric congruence was first introduced by Riemann (G.F.B.Riemann Elliptische Funklionen (Leipzig 1899), p 1, 6). (ref: paragraph 374 of Cajori's book)

Comment: @Travis For what it's worth, `=` in Mathematica is "immediate assignment" and `:=` is "delayed assignment" http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html

Answer (score 5):

The material here is extracted from Florian Cajori's book [A history of mathematical notations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486677664).
If there are any mistakes, it is most likely caused by my own misunderstanding.

The symbol $\equiv$ has been used by various branches of mathematics. It has been used for

1. **arithmetic** as congruence - first introduced by Gauss in $1801$.

   Ref: [an online reference](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/history/nth.html) and paragraph $408$ of Cajori's book.
2. **geometry** as geometric congruence - first introduced by Riemann.

   It appears in G.F.B.Riemann's Elliptische Funklionen (Leipzig 1899), p 1, 6.

   Ref: paragraph $374$ of Cajori's book.
3. **logic** - can be dated back at least to $1910$.

   It appears as 'definitional identity' in [E.H.Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._H._Moore), *Introduction to a Form of General Analysis* (1910) p.18. 
   In first volume of Whitehead and Russell's [Principia Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) (1910, p5-38), it has been
   used as bi-conditional (i.e $p \equiv q$ stands for $p$ implies $q$ and $q$ implies $p$) instead.

   Ref: paragraphs $694, 695$ of Cajori's book.

   Gottlob Ferge may have used $\equiv$ before in $1879$ (he switched to use $=$ later in his publication in $1893$), the reference I have is not clear what happens.

   Ref: paragraph $687$ of Cajori's book.

Comment: +1, but partly correct. W&R's [*Principia*](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA7) (see page 7 and 12) has $\equiv$ for bi-conditional and $=$ followed by Df. on the right-end od the formula for definitional identity.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA fixed, thanks for pointing that out.